# Regex replace with captured

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, regex-group

I want replace all non alphanumeric character in the string by it self surrender for "[" and "]".

I tried this:

```
var text = "ab!@1b*. ef";
var regex = /\W/g;

var result  = text.replace(regex, "[$0]");

console.log(result);
```

I was expecting to get:

> `ab[!][@]1b[*][.][ ]ef`

But instead i get:

> `ab[$0][$0]1b[$0][$0][$0]ef`

How can I do this using Javascript(node)?

Comment: No need to wrap with capturing groups. Use `text.replace(regex, "[$&]")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the group in parentheses to assign it to $1, like this:

```js
var text = "ab!@1b*. ef";
var regex = /(\W)/g;

var result  = text.replace(regex, "[$1]");

console.log(result);
```